# 3D model gets partially invisible when large, Vuforia and Unity

Tags: unity, android, 3d, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'd appreciate if someone could advise on my problem.

I use one on-device image target and a single 3D model. I use Unity extension and then export the scene to Android project. I also use Extended tracking.

My 3D model is looking fine when it's  small, see Screenshot1.png.

But if I try to make my 3D model larger by increasing the scale, and  when I move camera far from the target,  the  model gets partially invisible, see Screenshot2.png.

I tried to reposition my ARCamera but no luck.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are working within Unity?
If I am guessing right then please check your Main Camera's Distance option on where it does cut off, this is one of the main reasons of this problem.

Also can you give more information on your model? Are the texture maps baked? Is the lighting dynamic?

Comment: Correct, I work in Unity. There's actually no Main camera but AR Camera provided by Vuforia. How should I configure it? And I use this 3D model https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/29170, please check it out.

Answer (score -1):

So, the solution was quite simple, I needed to change Clipping Planes of Camera (child of ARCamera) by increasing `Far` property.

Comment: Instead of copying the answer, please just upvote/accept the answer.